# Not being able to upload image to django project

Tags: python, django, web, frameworks, portfolio

While I have the images stored into my 'img' file it  isn't showing up inside of my virtual environment, I will provide a screenshot of both the images inside of my file plus the virtual environment folder structure. Below is the error message.

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/projects/img/todo.png
'projects\img\todo.png' could not be found

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

[image]

Comment: Burbanoto how did you define your ```statics``` folders /?

Comment: While DEBUG = True, django doesn't share statistic files like your get request.

Comment: @musulmon how do I then get the files to share?

Answer (score 1):

It would've been much better if you included your urls.py and setting.py but I'm guessing you have not set the static root, in any case by reading [this django doc page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/) you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you it was resolved! I ran through check listing to make sure all directories were appropriately stored, I ran 'python manage.py collectstatic' then transferred the images back into my image file and I now have them appearing in my project. Yay!